# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET after serving app from ng

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I have an issue while running a newly generated project from Angular. Compilation completes and I understand that the server is running, but whenever I try to open http://localhost:4200 from any browser, it loads for a very long time and gives the error- ERR_CONNECTION_RESET and that some files were unable to load because of this.

I see my app title at the top and even the fav icon, but the site itself doesn't render at all. I tried the following:-

1. Restarting my system
2. Clean reinstalling both npm and ng cli
3. Downgrading to Angular 8
4. Clearing my browser cache
5. Confirming I have no proxies setup

None of these worked and I'm essentially stuck without a way forward now.

When I do a GET call from PostMan, I do get an index.html response, but from Chrome, Firefox and even Edge nothing renders.

I tested to see if the node server installed in my system itself works, and I could confirm it works by serving a GET endpoint that returns 'Hello World!'

Thanks in advance for any help possible.